# java script for a drop down selected index change

Tags: javascript, jquery

i  2 Dropdown  controls  and  1  text  box
 In drop down1  one  i have the  values like  11.00,11.30,12.00,12.30,13.00, 13.30
 In drop down2  one  i have the  values like  11.30,12.00,12.30,13.00, 13.30, 14.00

once the user  selects the  values  in drop down 1 and  drop down 2  an  event  will  fires in drop  down 2. where  the selected vales from drop down 1 and drop down 2   are  taken. the     dropdown1 value is  subtracted  from  dropdown2 value .
 if condition comes like  11.30 - 11.00= .30   if  .30 is  the  result it  should  be  shown as  .50   as  a result in text box
 if condition comes like  11.00 - 10.30= .70   if  .70 is  the  result it  should  be  shown as  .50   as  a result in text box

this  condition should as    work in  javascript

if any  one  know s  how   to  do  it,  help  me  out
  thank  you

Comment: eh?  you want to subtract one time from another?  Where does the .70 come from and how does that equal .50?

Comment: What should be the result when the value is .10 or .90?

Comment: should it always show .50 in the text box?

Comment: 14 questions and you haven't accepted one answer? C'mon man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a bit of a whim I decided that you want to calculate the difference between two times...  Ignore me if it's not what you're after but I fancied doing it anyway.  To make it easier I set the values in the drop downs to number of minutes cos working with time in js can be a ball ache:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        //Calculate the difference when second ddl changes
        $("#ddl2").change(function() {calculateTimeDiff();});
   });

   function calculateTimeDiff() {
    //get the values
    var time1 = $("#ddl1").val();   
    var time2 = $("#ddl2").val();

    //check everything is in the right state to do the calc
    if(time1 > time2) {
        alert("time 1 must be before time 2");
    }
    else {              
        //get the number of mins difference
        var minsDiff = (time2 - time1);     
        //remove number of hours (60 min chunks)
        minsDiff = minsDiff % 60;
        //get hours difference
        var hoursDiff = time2 - time1 - minsDiff;
        //if more than none, get the no of whole hours
        if (hoursDiff > 0) {        
            hoursDiff = hoursDiff/60;           
        }
        //format mins diff
        if(minsDiff == 0) { minsDiff = "00"};
        //add it to text box
        $("#text1").val(hoursDiff + ":" + minsDiff);                                
    }   
   }
</script>

<div id="example">
    <select id="ddl1"> 
        <option value="600">10:00</option>
        <option value="630">10:30</option>
        <option value="660">11:00</option>
        <option value="690">11:30</option>
        <option value="720">12:00</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ddl2"> 
        <option value="630">10:30</option>
        <option value="660">11:00</option>
        <option value="690">11:30</option>
        <option value="720">12:00</option>
        <option value="750">12:30</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="text1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add 'onchange="calculate()"' in your dropdown 2
add this javascript function

```
function calculate()
{
   var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1')
   var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown1')
   var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox')
   var a = dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex]
   var b = dropdown2.options[dropdown2.selectedIndex]
   if((a -b) == what ever you want)
      textbox.value = what ever you want
   else if((a -b) == what ever you want)
      textbox.value = what ever you want

}
```

Comment: hi , thanks 4  ur replay . this   gives  me  to   finish the basic thing    where i can  find the diffreence  between  2 number's
   
1  condition: where if the result is    1.30  , 2.30 then  i  should  show  the result intext box as  1.50, 2,50

 2  condition: 1.70  , 2.70 then  i  should  show  the result intext box as  1.50, 2,50thank  you

Comment: var c = a-b
if(c==1.30 || c == 2.30){textbox.value = "1.50,2.50"}
else if(c==1.70 || c == 2.70){textbox.value = "1.50,2.50"}

hope this helps,anyway before writing javascript you should start learning a bit about the language like the basics (conditions, loop, ...) try google, you'll find alot.

Answer (score 0):

Code in jQuery without the replacing part. I am not sure about your 2 conditions. do you want to always show .50 if the result is .30 or .70.

**Updated**

```
<script>
$(document).ready ( function () {      
  $("#sel1").change ( function () {      
    CalcResult ();
  });

  $("#sel2").change ( function () {    
     CalcResult ();
  });


  function CalcResult ()
  {
    var resultVal = parseFloat ( $("#sel2 option:selected").val() ) - parseFloat ( "#sel1 option:selected").val() );         

    var resultVal = $("#sel2 option:selected").val() - $("#sel1 option:selected").val();

    resultVal = resultVal.toFixed("2").toString().replace ( ".30" , ".50" ).replace(".70" , ".50" );

    $("#txt1").val(resultVal.toFixed("2"));
}

});
</script>

<body>
<select id="sel1"> 
    <option value="11.00">11.00</option> 
    <option value="11.30">11.30</option> 
    <option value="12.00">12.00</option> 
    <option value="12.30">12.30</option> 
    <option value="13.00">13.00</option> 
    <option value="13.3">13.30</option> 
  </select> 
  <select id="sel2"> 
    <option value="11.30">11.30</option> 
    <option value="12.00">12.00</option> 
    <option value="12.30">12.30</option> 
    <option value="13.00">13.00</option> 
    <option value="13.30">13.30</option> 
    <option value="14.00">14.0</option> 
  </select> 

  <input type="text" id="txt1" /> 
</body>
```